# Cypher query to find the "best" person to introduce Tom Hanks to Tom Cruise

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm going through the `neo4j 3.0.6` Movie Graph example and am at the part where we *"Find someone to introduce Tom Hanks to Tom Cruise."* After executing

```
MATCH (tom:Person {name:"Tom Hanks"})-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(coActors),
      (coActors)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m2)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(cruise:Person {name:"Tom Cruise"})
RETURN tom, m, coActors, m2, cruise
```

I get the following graph:
[image]

What Cypher query would rank co-actors according to those who have the most connections with Tom Hanks AND Tom Cruise first? The result would look similar to:

```
Name        , connecting_movies, (OR) connecting_edges
Meg Ryan    , 4                , 8
Bonnie Hunt , 2                , 4
Kevin Bacon , 2                , 4
```

Comment: It's great that you got an acceptable answer. But it doesn't belong in your question as an update (that's what upvoting or accepting an answer is for). That's why I rolled it back.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @DavidMakogon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're only looking at one relationship type (:ACTED_IN), it should be sufficient to use the number of common movies and leave out edges (edges would be 2x number of movies anyway, unless one of the actors played multiple roles within the same movie, but that doesn't seem like it would be a meaningful measure of a stronger connection).

However, we have to ensure we consider only distinct movies when we get the count, as it's possible that there could be a single movie in which all those involved acted (Tom, Tom, and the coactor), and we only want to count that movie once, and not twice. To ensure we get that distinct count, we'll need to combine both columns of movies (m and m2) into a single column, and then get a distinct count of movies in that column.

Unfortunately, at this point in time Neo4j's UNION won't allow us to continue to work on the unioned results (to get the count), so we have to instead turn each column of movies into a collection, add the collections together, then unwind that single collection into a single column of movies. The final query looks like this:

```
MATCH (:Person {name:"Tom Hanks"})-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(coActors)
MATCH (coActors)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m2)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(:Person {name:"Tom Cruise"})
WITH coActors, collect(m) + collect(m2) as allMovies
UNWIND allMovies as moviesInCommon
RETURN coActors, COUNT(DISTINCT moviesInCommon) as commonMoviesCnt
ORDER BY commonMoviesCnt DESC
```

EDIT I changed your first MATCH into two MATCHES, since in the single match line, a movie in m would not be matched in m2 (I encourage you to change the query in your description to also be 2 matches). While this would give us distinct counts (something we want), it would also prevent us from correctly matching on coactors who acted alongside both actors-of-interest in the same movies.

You can test this by changing your persons of interest to Tom Hanks and Meg Ryan. Of course, they already know each other and need no introduction, but using these two can better show which queries work correctly when both actors coacted in the same movie(s).

Comment: You can replace lines 4-6 with a simple `RETURN coActors, SIZE(allMovies) ORDER BY size(allMovies)`. Performing an `UNWIND` only to re-aggregate with `COUNT` won't get you much :)

Comment: @ToreEschliman We need the UNWIND so we can get the distinct count. If we can use a set instead of a collection, removing duplicates as we combine the collections, then you would be correct. Given, if the intent of the query is to introduce two people who have never coacted together, then were wouldn't be duplicates, but I'm covering the case where that could happen.

Comment: It seems like we should filter for that case way at the top... any count of movies is meaningless if they have a movie in common already.

Comment: If you mean that with movies in common they no longer need to be introduced so no query is really needed, then yes, agreed. I am stretching with my query, but it does answer the original question, and can also be used to answer different, yet similar, questions ("which coactor of two actors has the strongest total connection to them based on movies in common?", "if two actors got selective amnesia and forgot about each other, which coactor might be best to reintroduce them?" and so on). The point is that the query is portable, even among actors who have already coacted with each other.

Comment: If we have an actor who acted in 2 different movies with each of them, we give her a score of 4. If another actor was in 3 movies, each with both of them, this gives her a score of only 3, even though for each person, she was actually in *more* movies together than the first actor. If you're trying to find strength of relationship, the second case seems like it should rank higher, but that's a question for the query writer to determine I guess :)

Answer (score 1):

[UPDATED]

Your single `MATCH` clause forces the `m` and `m2` counts to always be the same, meaning that for a particular `coActor` the `m` or `m2` nodes can appear multiple times. To avoid this duplication, you can split it into 2 `MATCH` clauses and get the counts separately, as follows. This query also filters out movies that both Toms acted in, since that implies they no longer need to be introduced.

```
MATCH (a1:Person {name:"Tom Hanks"}), (a2:Person {name:"Tom Cruise"})
MATCH (a1)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m1)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(coActor)
WHERE NOT (a2)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m1)
WITH a1, a2, coActor, COUNT(m1) AS c1
MATCH (coActor)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m2)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(a2)
WHERE NOT (a1)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m2)
WITH coActor, (c1 + COUNT(m2)) AS connecting_movies
RETURN coActor.name AS name, connecting_movies, 2*connecting_movies AS connecting_edges
ORDER BY connecting_movies DESC;
```

Comment: While it works in the case of Tom Cruise and Tom Hanks, this query starts to give inaccurate results when there are movies in which both actors coacted (given, since they coacted they no longer need to be introduced to each other, so it wouldn't really apply given the intent of the query). Change this to Tom Hanks and Meg Ryan and you should see the numbers don't quite add up.

Comment: @InverseFalcon: Great point. I have modified my answer by ignoring in which movies in which both actors acted.